# Finding a specific point on an OBB (Oriented Bounding Box)

Tags: math, vector, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

[image]

Hello, I've got a question which I cannot solve so I need a bit help.

In the picture above you can see an Oriented Bounding Box specified by 4 points (A, B, C, D). There is also a point in space called P. If I cast a ray from P against the OBB the ray is going to intersect the OBB at some point. This point of intersection is called Q in the picture. By the way the ray is always going to be x-axis aligned which means its directional vector is either (1, 0) or (-1,0) if normalized. My goal is to find the point of intersection - Q. Is there a way (if possible computationaly inexpensive) to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to consider each side of the bounding box to be a linear equation of the form `y = ax + b`, where `a` is the slope and `b` is the y-intercept. Then consider the ray from P to be an equation of the form `y = c`, where c is a constant. Then compare this equation to each of the four other equations to see where it intersects each one. One of these intersections will be our Q, if a Q exists; it's possible that the ray will miss the bounding box entirely. We will need to do a few checks:

- Firstly, eliminate all potential Q's that are on the wrong side of P.
- Secondly, check each of the four intersections to make sure they are within the bounds of the lines that they represent, and eliminate the ones that are not.
- Finally, if any potential Q's remain, the one closest to P will be our Q. If no potential Q's remain, this means that the ray from P misses the bounding box entirely.

For example...

The line drawn from D to B would have a slope equal to `(B.y - D.y) / (B.x - D.x)` and a y-intercept equal to `B.y - B.x * slope`. Then the entire equation is `y = (B.y - D.y) / (B.x - D.x) * x + B.y - B.x * (B.y - D.y) / (B.x - D.x)`. Set this equation equal to `y = P.y` and solve for x:

```
x = (P.y - B.y + B.x*(B.y - D.y)/(B.x - D.x))*(B.x - D.x)/(B.y - D.y)
```

The result of this equation will give you the x-value of the intersection. The y-value is `P.y`. Do this for each of the other 3 lines as well: A-B, A-C, C-D. I will refer to these intersections as Q(D-B), Q(A-B), Q(A-C), and Q(C-D) respectively.

1. Next, eliminate candidate-Q's that are on the wrong side of P. In our example, this eliminates Q(A-B), since it is way off to the right side of the screen. Mathematically, `Q(A-B).x > P.x`.
2. Then eliminate all candidate-Q's that are not on the line they represent. We can do this check by finding the lowest and highest x-values and y-values given by the two points that represent the line. For example, to check that Q(A-C) is on the line A-C, check that `C.x <= Q(A-C).x <= A.x` and `C.y <= Q(A-C).y <= A.y`. Q(A-C) passes the test, as well as Q(D-B). However, Q(C-D) does not pass, as it is way off to the left side of the screen, far from the box. Therefore, Q(C-D) is eliminated from candidacy.
3. Finally, of the two points that remain, Q(A-C) and Q(D-B), we choose Q(D-B) to be our winner, because it is closest to P.

We now can say that the ray from P hits the bounding box at Q(D-B).

Of course, when you implement this in code, you will need to account for divisions by zero. If a line is perfectly vertical, there does not exist a point-slope equation of the line, so you will need to create a separate formula for this case. If a line is perfectly horizontal, it's respective candidate-Q should be automatically eliminated from candidacy, as the ray from P will never touch it.

**Edit:**
It would be more efficient to only do this process with lines whose two points are on vertically opposite sides of point P. If both points of a line are above P, or they are both below P, they would be eliminated from candidacy from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Find the two sides that straddle `p` on `Y`. (Test of the form `(Ya < Yp) != (Yb < Yp)`).

Then compute the intersection points of the horizontal by `p` with these two sides, and keep the first to the left of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

If the ray points to the left(right) then it must intersect an edge that connects to the point in the OOB with max(min) x-value. We can determine which edge by simply comparing the y-value of the ray with the y value of the max(min) point and its neighbors. We also need to consider OBBs that are actually axis-aligned, and thus have two points with equal max(min) x-value. Once we have the edge it's simple to confirm that the ray does in fact intersect the OBB and calculate its x-value.

Here's some Java code to illustrate ([ideone](https://ideone.com/Ynivft)):

```
static double nearestX(Point[] obb, int y, int dir)
{
    // Find min(max) point
    int n = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++) 
        if((obb[n].x < obb[i].x) == (dir == -1)) n = i;
    
    // Determine next or prev edge  
    int next = (n+1) % 4;
    int prev = (n+3) % 4;
    
    int nn;     
    if((obb[n].x == obb[next].x) || (obb[n].y < y) == (obb[n].y < obb[next].y)) 
        nn = next;
    else 
        nn = prev;

    // Check that the ray intersects the OBB
    if(Math.abs(y) > Math.abs(obb[nn].y)) return Double.NaN;
    
    // Standard calculation of x from y for line segment
    return obb[n].x + (y-obb[n].y)*(obb[nn].x-obb[n].x)/(obb[nn].y-obb[n].y);       
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test("Diamond", new Point[]{p(0, -2), p(2, 0), p(0, 2), p(-2,0)});
    test("Square", new Point[]{p(-2, -2), p(2, -2), p(2, 2), p(-2,2)});
}

static void test(String label, Point[] obb)
{
    System.out.println(label + ": " + Arrays.toString(obb));
    for(int dir : new int[] {-1, 1})
    {
        for(int y : new int[] {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3})
            System.out.printf("(% d, % d) = %.0f\n", y , dir, nearestX(obb, y, dir));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Diamond: [(0,-2), (2,0), (0,2), (-2,0)]
(-3, -1) = NaN
(-2, -1) = 0
(-1, -1) = 1
( 0, -1) = 2
( 1, -1) = 1
( 2, -1) = 0
( 3, -1) = NaN

(-3,  1) = NaN
(-2,  1) = 0
(-1,  1) = -1
( 0,  1) = -2
( 1,  1) = -1
( 2,  1) = 0
( 3,  1) = NaN

Square: [(-2,-2), (2,-2), (2,2), (-2,2)]
(-3, -1) = NaN
(-2, -1) = 2
(-1, -1) = 2
( 0, -1) = 2
( 1, -1) = 2
( 2, -1) = 2
( 3, -1) = NaN

(-3,  1) = NaN
(-2,  1) = -2
(-1,  1) = -2
( 0,  1) = -2
( 1,  1) = -2
( 2,  1) = -2
( 3,  1) = NaN
```